# Start a thread a second time

Tags: java, android

```
thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(!requestedToExit)
                {
                    SystemClock.sleep(3000);
                    Log.d("debug", "in");
                }
            }
        };
```

So a button got an event, Each time I click on it it's start the thread (if the previous thread is not alive).

So I tried use thread.start() but it throw thread already started. I tried .run(), nothing happens, I also tried each time I click on the button, and it's possible to run it again, create a new thread and start it : nothing.

Some ideas ?

---

Using Runnable :

```
   r= new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                while(!requestedToExit)
                {
                    Log.d("debug", "in");
                    SystemClock.sleep(3000);

                }
            }
        };
```

Then I use in my listener :

```
thread = new Thread(injection);
thread.start();
```

But I only see the debug the first time, he never enter into it after.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) -

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Instead, use `java.lang.Runnable` and create a new thread to run it when you have to.

What you need to do is:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ....
    }
};
```

Then, when you want to start it:

```
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
```

You need to always create a new thread to run that one runnable.

Comment: I edited my first post. Thanks in advance
PS : I wanted to use the function from Thread and Runnable too, .isAlive is pretty useful for me.

Comment: I re-edited my first post. I don't use Thread t = new Thread(r) but t = new Thread(r) because I define it at the beginning private Thread thread = new Thread();, else I cannot know if my thread isAlive() the first time, but I think it's not the problem because I use new Thread(). Thanks for your help

Comment: God I'm retarded, forgot to set requestedToExit at false... Thanks